# T-SQL Distinct Same Tablo and Select Multi Column And Id lenth > 5

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

First, thanks for your time and your help!

```
EventId       UserId         Description

---------------------------------------

2525123547     2     lorem lorem lorem  ghfgh    
2525123547     2     saddsadddasdsdsdsddsasd      
2525123547     5     saddsadddasdsdsdsddsasdgfghfhgh   
252            2     saddsadddasdsdsdsddsasd
1454           2     343444434343dffdfdfdfd jfdfjdfj fdjfdj lorem lorem
1522254412     5     dsadadfsffsafasfdsdsdsadsddsaasddd
1555224451     2     sadasdsadasdddsadaddsad
1555224451     2     asdafgewrwerrewrererewrwrerww
```

I want to do a distinct operation according to EventId. I would like to see the result of the user process as follows. And

EventId length must be greater than 5

```
For exp  where UserId =2


EventId          UserId     Description
2525123547        2         lorem lorem lorem  ghfgh
1555224451        2         sadasdsadasdddsadaddsad
```

Comment: How to chose which row to return for an eventid?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Could you elaborate it? Or give resultset you want to get?

Comment: I want to return a value back to UserId.

Answer (score 0):

Use a ROW_NUMBER to assign 1 to the row you want to return:

```
with cte as 
 ( select ...
      row_number()
      over (partition by UserId, EventId -- for each user (if UserId removed from WHERE) & Event
            order by whatever_determines_your_result) as rn 
   from tab
   where UserId = 2
     and length(EventId) > 5
 )
select *
from cte 
where rn = 1
```

Comment: @josephanzel:Ops, I forgot to add EventId to PARTITION, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't understand exactly what you mean, but from the distinction point of view, you may consider such a query :

```
select t2.EventId, t2.UserId, t2.Description 
  from
    (
    select t.*, len(t.Description) as l_desc,
           row_number() over (partition by EventId order by len(t.Description)) as rn
      from tab t
     where UserId =2
       and len(EventId) > 5
     ) t2
  where rn = 2
  order by EventId desc;

EventId     UserId  Description
----------  ------  ------------------------------
2525123547    2     lorem lorem lorem  ghfgh
1555224451    2     asdafgewrwerrewrererewrwrerww
```

*P.S. I don't have any idea about the logic for the column description.*

Comment: Aynı eventId den sadece 1 tanesinin geriye değer döndürmesini istiyorum. Sonuç tablosuna tekrar bakar mısınız?

Comment: @josephanzel hocam merhaba. Sizin örneğe göre UserId = 2 olunca zaten aynı eventId'den bir tanesi dönmekte ... Eğer UserId sabit değilse eventidlerden hangi şarta uyan gelmeli...

Comment: hocam yukarıdaki tabloyu güncelledim. tekrar kontrol eder misiniz. aynı eventId den 1 tanesi dönsün ancak hangisinin döndüğünün bir önemi yok